# Dynamics AX work flow keep receiving lots of deadlock error

Tags: workflow, deadlock, ax

Recently see lots of same error message on AX workflow batch job as below :

**Can not select a record in Table messages workflow (WorkflowMessageTable). Message ID workflow: {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}, {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}. Deadlock. One or more users have locked simultaneously the entire table or part of it.**

Could anyone advise how to fix this issue? 
Would this cause system loading or bad efficiency of workflow process since our workflow looks dead during daytime but comes alive in the night?

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, but analyzing deadlocks without access to the system, is next to impossible. Also it is debatable weather this is programming related.

Comment: Thanks, Jan. Could this give you a lead that this deadlock is only alarmed in AX batch job history but not in SQL server ?

Answer (score 1):

Finally found the root cause of this error, it's the batch job comes along while previous one is not finished yet.

After increased the time between process to 10 min from 4, the error is stopped.